# Install Ruby specific version using YUM

Tags: ruby, repository, installation, rvm, yum

I am wondering if i could set up a local **YUM** repository and place my **RUBY** source code( v 1.9.3-p194) over there and use YUM INSTALL RUBY-1.9.3-p194 to install on my system.

1) Is it possible?
2) How does this **YUM INSTALL** works?

I am thinking of doing this without RVM support for we don't want the existence of RVM in our production.

Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: You need exactly the `p194` or the last `1.9.3` version is good enough?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#yum) are the instructions to use yum for ruby installation. In the link, there's another link to the gentoo project (used by yum) where you can find [this info:](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Ruby):

```
Right now, we include the following Ruby implementations in Gentoo.

  ruby20 - Ruby MRI 2.0 (deprecated)
  ruby21 - Ruby MRI 2.1
  ruby22 - Ruby MRI 2.2 (testing)
  ruby23 - Ruby MRI 2.3 (testing)
```

So, no, i think you can't install this version with yum. I'm afraid you'll need to install it from source:

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#building-from-source

Comment: Seems that yum for RHEL/CentOS is divergent from Gentoo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, you can build your own RPM package, set up your own YUM repository, and install it with YUM. (That is, after all, just what your Linux distribution does: build an RPM package and put it in a YUM repository.) That's what YUM is for: installing RPM packages from YUM repositories.